# stubhub objective-c api request token for event search

Tags: objective-c, api

I think that´s a pretty basic problem: I would like to search for events on "stubhub" with e.g. this request:

```
https://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v2?point=40.2,-83.1&radius=120&minAvailableTickets=1&date=2014-06-01T00:00 TO 2014-06-01T23:59&sort=distance Bearer nPdKiqkoTwAAsKzKFhHJfZeskE0a
```

So when I send the request it gives me:

```
<ams:fault><ams:code>900902</ams:code><ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Required OAuth credentials not provided</ams:description></ams:fault>
```

Ok, so of course it seems like I need to have a token or any authentication in the request. The documentation is pretty confusing and I don´t get how to pass the auth along with the reqeust. Other Apis just wants a "token=" parameter but I can´t find what stubhub wants to have here! After the request I want to parse it in xcode... I´m really stuck on this problem...Thx!

Api-Docs: https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Search&api=EventSearchAPI&endpoint=searchforevents&version=v2

Comment: i dont see where the documentation says to put in your apptoken, consumersecret, or consumerkey either

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in your browser without a token, if you want to make an actual http request obviously need token. trying to figure out if unirest is compatible with the api, you can use the sandbox environment though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to email apisupport@stubhub.com and ask for access I've been struggling to invoke this call as well for the past week I finally stumbled upon this email and I emailed support and they granted me access and now I can invoke this endpoint. Also instead of v2 has to be v3 namespace

Comment: ya sorry just figured it out myself still having trouble with stubhubs api though lol

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its pretty involved - and you probably cant do it in a browser? Because at first glance you'll need to set the header information. [Source](https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/userguide.jag).